# MSBuild on Buildserver fails because already build parts are deleted

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity

I try to build a .Net solution with Teamcity and msbuild. If I set the "Visual Studio (sln)" build step target to "build" everything works (as on my local machine). But if I set the target to "rebuild" it doesn't find libraries:

```
vbc error BC2017: could not find library 'C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\123456bbbbbbbb\foo\bin\Release\bar.dll'
```

But if I look in this folder during the build I see that this files are created, and after some time, deleted again.

I use TeamCity 9.1.7 and Visual Studio 2015.

Any idea why and how that can be fixed?

Regards!
    Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I would check your VSC setup and cleanup rules. It's likely that upon checkout your local artifacts are cleaned up.